# Slick slider arrows hidden when total number of slides and slides shown are equal and the slider is not sliding also

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slick.js

So I have tried many ways. What I'm trying to achieve is I only have 3 slides but show 3 slides also. Whenever I put `slidesToShow: 3` the slider stops working and arrows hidden.

My code is below. Please help.

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: false,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
  initialSlide: 0,
});

$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  arrows: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />

<div class="slider slider-for">
    <div>
      <div class="quote">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="quote">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="quote">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider-nav">
      <div>
        <div class="quote-image">
          <img src="https://demo.plugins360.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/demo.png" alt="" width="200px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="quote-image">
          <img src="https://demo.plugins360.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/demo.png" alt="" width="200px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="quote-image">
          <img src="https://demo.plugins360.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/demo.png" alt="" width="200px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

set slidesToShow: 2.99
that's my answer

Comment: Can you add more info as to why it fixes it

Comment: I had 2 slides, `slidesToShow: 2` and `infinite: true` but still the arrows were hidden. Setting `slidesToShow: 1.99` did the trick and now scrolling works again.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have 3 slides and `slidesToShow: 3`, there's nothing to scroll. If the slides are not fully visible, you could try removing your `centerMode: true` setting.

```js
$('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    arrows: true,
});
```

If you want things to scroll regardless of the count, you could try setting `infinite: true`.

Comment: I also encounter this Slick slider arrows hidden when total number of slides and slides shown are equal 
In this codepen even though infinite is already set to true the arrows are still not showing.. any thoughts?
( https://codepen.io/davecar21/pen/RwovWvB )